# How to empty a cell

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array that contains a lot of NaN. But for whatever reason the `isnan` function can't detect them (hence this doesn't work `cellfun(@(Iarray) any(isnan(Iarray)),Iarray);`) so I figured it was actually strings that contains `NaN`.

I perform two things on this array : cleaning empty rows and columns and removing NaN (well trying to).

So I want to replace all the NaN by empty cells and then perform to clean all empty cells with the `isempty` function. I'll use a loop and `if char(x(i,j))=='NaN'`.

So here comes my problem I want to empty a cell and then detect that cell with the `isempty` function but I have no idea how. I have tried `x(1,2)= []`, `x(1,2)= {[]}`, `x(1,2)=''` but none of those gives a `1` for `isempty(x(1,2))` for example.

Does anyone know how to solve my problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `x{1,2}= []`.

Comment: @rahnema1 ohhhh! I also have to put `{}` in the `isempty` function! thank you! Can you put your comment in the answers so I can accept it?

Comment: @Arthur true. But I think my problem was more on finding that I had to put {} in the `isempty ` function

Comment: Sure! Please see the answer.

Comment: @JackA That is why I retracted the duplicate flag immediately when I saw your comment .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to empty the content of a cell you can use :

```
x{1,2} = [];
```

There is a difference between indexing using parentheses `()` and brackets `{}`. You can think a cell array as an *array of cells* that each cell contains a value such as `1 ,2 , []`. When a cell is indexed with parentheses it returns the result as cell (or more precisely as an array of type cell) but when it is indexed with brackets it returns the *content* of the cell (or more precisely as a [comma separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) containing the contents of the indexed cells). So when you write such an expression:

```
x(1,2) = [];
```

It removes the second element from the array of cells and behaves like indexing other array types. For example when you want to remove the second element of `a = [1 2 3]` you can use `a(2)=[]`.

But when you write `x{1,2} = [];` it accesses the *content* of the cell and sets it to a null array `[0 x 0]` of type double that is empty.

Likewise `a={}` is a `[0 x 0]` null array of cells and `b={[]}` is an `[1 x 1]` array of cells that its first element contains a null array `[0 x 0]` of type double. When you use `isempty(b)` it returns `false` because it contains an element and when you use `isempty(b(1))` it returns `false` because `b(1)` returns an array of cells that contains an element but when you use `isempty(b{1})` it returns `true` because the `{}` operator extracts the contents of the first cell that is a null array.

In short, cells can be accessed using both `()` and `{}`, and based on the situation `[]` has different functionalities: `a)` removing element `b)` null array.

Comment: Nice explanation!